# O365 subscription renewal is throwing unknown exception

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm working on a sync server that keeps the Office 365 events and my calendering app in sync. Service subscribes to a push notification for user's event calendar that has a custom single extended property.

The subscription is renewed every two days to keep the subscription active. Recently we started observing errors in subscription renew API and the exception doesn't have much details. These errors are happening for lot of subscriptions (> 1000) Any idea why these errors are observed.

Error response received for url

```
 PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>
```

Sample request body

```
{
 "expirationDateTime" :"2018-11-01T04:55:54.304Z"
}
```

Response code 500 Body

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "An unknown error occurred.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "<request_id>",
            "date": "2018-10-28T08:31:40"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the request body ?

Comment: @kikang updated the description with sample request body. The same request used to work without any issues for at least a couple of months. But started failing from past 4 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had observed a partial outage of Microsoft Graph Subscription Service for few Azure Instances in US starting Friday, 26th October 4 PM PDT.

We discovered these intermittent failures on Monday, October 29th evening and successfully fixed the issues by 8 PM PDT on same day.

This should not cause the Subscription data corruption. You should be able to use all your active subscriptions.

We regret the inconvenience caused and we are working with very high priority to discover these issues proactively & fix sooner.

Please let us know if you still see any issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It would be great if there is a public status page for all Microsoft graph services and updated proactively. This would be very helpful for API consumers.